# Flickering line on the screen for about 1 second after transitioning between different view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, screen

I opened Xcode and all I've done is creating 3 view controllers and embedded an image view for the background into all of them.

And after that, I embedded a navigation controller.

When I run the app, it correctly opens, but when I press the button to transition to different view controller, a vertical flickering line appears.

When I go back using the navigation controller, even on the main screen the flickering line appears.

That's just the start of an app, and such a problem. That was all I did, all done on the main storyboard, I didn't write even a line of code inside the viewcontroller.swift or anywhere else.